# Calender Control in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

As there is no default calender control in windows phone 8, i wonder what would be best practice to implement a calender control. Any suggestions.

Note:
- No use of third party controls.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of DateTimePicker control, in Windows Phone toolkit. ie the only option you have. Otherwise you can create your own control for achieving the functionality

Answer (score -1):

If you have RadControls for Windows Phone, you can use theirs [Calendar](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/calendar.aspx) control. Note that it is not free and it costs 100$.

However, if you enrolled into Nokia's Premium Developer Program, you can get both the controls and a token for Windows Phone Dev account for the same amount of money you will give already for Dev Account.

Disclaimer: I am not working for any of the above companies.